# SignalR 2.0 The namespace '' already contains a definition for 'Startup'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I tried to follow a tutorial on SignalR 2.0. with ASP.NET MVC 4.0
I build the new Startup class as instructed.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MyApp.Startup))]

namespace MyApp
{
  public class Startup
  {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
      // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=316888
      app.MapSignalR();
    }
  }
}
```

When I tried to build the project. I got The namespace 'MyApp' already contains a definition for 'Startup' . 
I have search the whole project and physical folders to find where the second Startup,cs is but I could not find it.

Can anyone share some light on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I found the duplicate. It was defined in BundleConfig.cs. Removed it from BundleConfig.cs and it builds fine. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try making your Startup class partial:

```
public partial class Startup
```

Comment: Halter, thanks for the response. just try it and got another error of Error "Missing partial modifier on declaration of type 'MyApp.Startup'; another partial declaration of this type exists"

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a Startup class elsewhere in your project? I think that one might have been generated for you.